# options for creating sproc variable in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a sproc with multiple selects and result sets.  The last query in the sproc needs to select data where a table created date >= the first day of the current month.  I have SQL which successfully returns the first day of the month as expected.  I need to select this value into a sproc variable FirstDayOfTheMonth and then reference this variable in the WHERE clause of the subsequent SELECT statement in the sproc.  I included the following SQL before the final result set in the sproc but it seems that MySQL doesn't like something about it - something about its structure, positioning or syntax:

```
DECLARE FirstDayOfMonth INT DEFAULT 0;
SET FirstDayOfMonth = (SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()))- 1 DAY)
```

How can I update my existing attempt at a MySQL sproc variable so that my sproc compiles successfully with this variable declaration?

**UPDATE**

I tried to put the following 2 lines immediately after the BEGIN keyword in my sproc:

```
DECLARE FirstDayOfMonth INT DEFAULT 0;
SET FirstDayOfMonth = (SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()))- 1 DAY)
```

MySQL Workbench displays an error on the SET statement:

> FirstDayOfMonth is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

Any idea what I need to do differently here?

Comment: Your parentheses are not balanced. Could the error be coming from the next line?

Answer (score 0):

The `DECLARE`-statements need to be in the beginning of the procedure, before anything else, just after the `BEGIN`.

Comment: I tried the approach that you mentioned but my sproc still doesn't compile.  please see the info that I added under the "UPDATE" section of my original post.  thanks!

Comment: yep the issue was with my sql to get first day of month.  for example, setting the variable to a simple int worked as expected.  thanks!